# Surprising behaviour when using functools.partial in default argument inside a class

Tags: python, class, partial, functools

```
class A:

    def _add(a, b):
        return a + b
    
    def f_add():
        return _add
    
    def lambda_add():
        return lambda x, y: _add(x, y)
    
    def lambda_arg_add(l=lambda x, y: _add(x, y)):
        return l

    def partial_add():
        return partial(_add)
    
    def partail_arg_add(f=partial(_add)):
        return f


A.f_add()(1, 2)

A.lambda_add()(1, 2)

A.lambda_arg_add()(1, 2)

A.partial_add()(1, 2)

A.partail_arg_add()(1, 2)
```

All the function calls except the last one raise an error saying `_add` is not defined but the call to `partail_arg_add` executes successfully. What is the logic behind this? Why does the interpreter know where to look for `_add` when creating the partial function but only when it's done as a default argument?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### functools.partial is not involved in this behavior.

This is because the default arg is created at the function definition, during the class definition, which occur in the scope of the class, so you don't need any "self.".

This is why this works :

```py
class Example:
    def A(self):
        pass

    def B(self, x=print(A, 1)):
        print(self.A, 2)

    print(A, 3)
```

Output:

```
<function Example.A at 0x7fcf8ebc5950> 1
<function Example.A at 0x7fcf8ebc5950> 3
```

Even without calling any `Example.B()`, it should print the `<function Example.A at 0x7fcf8ebc5950>` 1 and 3 when the class is defined.

#### But you can't create a partial with a method of a non-yet created class

Or, maybe you can, but I am not aware of any way to do it.

I tried to fix you class:

```py
class A:
    @staticmethod
    def _add(a, b):
        return a + b

    @classmethod
    def f_add(cls):  # valid
        return cls._add

    @classmethod
    def lambda_add(cls):  # valid
        return lambda x, y: cls._add(x, y)

    @staticmethod
    def lambda_arg_add(l=lambda x, y: A._add(x, y)):  # valid
        return l

    @classmethod
    def partial_add(cls):  # valid
        return partial(cls._add)

    @staticmethod
    def partial_arg_add(f=partial(_add)):  # TypeError: 'staticmethod' object is not callable
        return f
```

But partial_arg_add will fail because _add is not callable yet when the partial is created :

```py
class A:
    @staticmethod
    def _add(a, b):
        return a + b

    print(_add(1, 3))  # TypeError: 'staticmethod' object is not callable
```

```py
class A:
    @staticmethod
    def _add(a, b):
        return a + b


print(A._add(1, 3))  # 4
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a nice explanation. I take it the contents of the lambda are not evaluated until later and that's why that doesn't work?

Comment: Exactly, the code of the lambda is evaluated when you do `A.lambda_arg_add()(1, 2)`.